# How can I get ip address in Python3.4.3

Tags: ip

python3.4.3

How can get ip address?

I try this way:

`print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))`

but only get `127.0.0.1`

how can I get the real ip ??

Comment: This suggests something is wrong with the hosts file / name resolution on this machine.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I try it on my macbook.

Comment: and I try it on raspberry pi , print `127.0.0.1`  too

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
socket.getfqdn()
```

or

```
 socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) returns 127.0.0.1 on machines having the hostname in /etc/hosts as 127.0.0.1